# Reprojecting raster from 0 360 to -180 180 with cutting 180 meridian using gdalwarp

Tags: coordinate-system, gdal, geotiff-tiff, proj, gdalwarp

I have a geotiff raster image that has a coordinate system with longitudes from 0 to 360.
The horizontal center of the image is 180 longitude. See image below:

[image]

I want to transform it to EPSG:4326 SRS with -180 180 longtitude range. 
And I want the center of the image to be at Greenwich meridian (0). I guess this srs is very widely used. I expect the result look like this:

[image]

So I use a gdalwarp command to reproject:

```
gdalwarp -s_srs '+proj=latlong +datum=WGS84 +pm=180dW' -t_srs EPSG:4326 test_col.tif test_4326.tif
```

But I only get a tiff with bigger dimensions (more pixels) and EPSG:4326 metadata. The image itself looks the same, as the initial one. But I expect it to swap the hemispheres.

How do I gdalwarp an image to be strictly -180 180 EPSG:4326 with the center in 0 longitude?

This is gdalinfo of my initial file:

```
Origin = (-0.102272598067084,89.946211604095552)
Pixel Size = (0.204545196134167,-0.204423208191126)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=BAND
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (  -0.1022726,  89.9462116) (  0d 6' 8.18"W, 89d56'46.36"N)
Lower Left  (  -0.1022726, -89.9462116) (  0d 6' 8.18"W, 89d56'46.36"S)
Upper Right (     359.897,      89.946) (359d53'50.18"E, 89d56'46.36"N)
Lower Right (     359.897,     -89.946) (359d53'50.18"E, 89d56'46.36"S)
Center      ( 179.8975000,  -0.0000000) (179d53'51.00"E,  0d 0' 0.00"S)
```

This is gdalinfo after gdalwarp

```
Origin = (-180.102727401932952,89.946211604095552)
Pixel Size = (0.091397622896436,-0.091420837939082)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.1027274,  89.9462116) (180d 6' 9.82"W, 89d56'46.36"N)
Lower Left  (-180.1027274, -89.9699975) (180d 6' 9.82"W, 89d58'11.99"S)
Upper Right ( 179.8211116,  89.9462116) (179d49'16.00"E, 89d56'46.36"N)
Lower Right ( 179.8211116, -89.9699975) (179d49'16.00"E, 89d58'11.99"S)
Center      (  -0.1408079,  -0.0118929) (  0d 8'26.91"W,  0d 0'42.81"S)
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You could explicitly set the output coordinate range using the target extent option to gdalwarp (ie. "-te -180 -90 180 90") but you can also use the CENTER_LONG configuration option to force rewrapping around a new central longitude.  Something like this:

```
  gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84" -t_srs WGS84 ~/0_360.tif 180.tif  -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 \
           --config CENTER_LONG 0
```

Note also the "SOURCE_EXTRA=1000" warp option.  When doing rewrapping the source rectangle computation will get confused around the longitude interruption and lose some imagery.  This option says pull in some extra.  Without it you will see a data gap near the prime meridian.

I think that setting a prime meridian of 180dW as you did is not a good idea.

Comment: hmm, `--config CENTER_LONG 0` does nothing, the result is the same raster. Anything I miss here? Running on GDAL version 2.2.3.

Comment: @jurajb it does change the center longitude with GDAL 3.3.0

Answer (score 6):

Basically you need to cut the raster into two parts and piece them back together with a new offset/scale.

There's an example here of how to do that from [-180,180] to [0,360] with gdal_translate and the VRT driver: 
http://trac.osgeo.org/gdal/wiki/UserDocs/RasterProcTutorial

Scan down to the "5 min tutorial" and the details are under "Virtual Files". It should be simple enough to modify the example to suit.

Answer (score 4):

If you just want to view the raster in QGIS, you can set a custom projection with the parameter +lon_wrap=180.

My understanding of this is that, by default, proj4 wraps latitudes from 0 -> 360 to -180 -> 180. +lon_wrap=180 will effectively cancel out this wrapping, and display latitudes between 180 and 360 in the Western hemisphere.

The option +over should disable the wrapping altogether, but - at least in my case - the raster didn't display properly when that option was used.

See http://proj4.org/parameters.html#lon-wrap-over-longitude-wrapping for more information.

Comment: This gdalwarp with lon_wrap works for me: `gdalwarp -s_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=180' -t_srs '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84'`

Comment: Windows users:  use " instead of '. ie.:
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +lon_wrap=180" -t_srs "+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"

Answer (score 4):

This can be done in R with one line of code using the `rotate` function with the `raster` package.

load the raster package first.

```
library(raster)
your_raster <- raster("path/to/raster.tif")
rotated_raster <- rotate(your_raster)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that I built to reproject a single dim array of grid values using JavaScript from 0-360 to -180-180.

```
  let xstart = 180 / xres //xres is the number of values per 1 degree
  for (let y = 0; y < data.height; y++) {
    let index = (y * data.width) + 1,
    start = index + xstart,
    end = index + data.width
    array.splice(index, 0, ...array.splice(start, (end - start)))
  }
```