# QGIS and the South Pole: bug or feature?

Tags: qgis, antarctica

I am trying to work with some data from Antarctica in QGIS. I have defined this new projection:

```
+proj=laea +lat_0=-90 +lon_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

And started adding a few vector layers. One of these contains the location of meteorologic stations in the continent. No matter what I try, QGis never portraits the South Pole station:

[image]

Is this the result of an issue with the custom CRS or is it a bug with QGis?

Comment: It's not a problem with your CRS, I get it too - it seems generally flaky overall - often other points don't show either - but interesting that you don't see that?  You'll probably find it works if you reproject your points layer so that it's not "on the fly". (Are you using "on the fly"? Also, what is your point source - I used CSV). I tried a few points directly off centre, at different longitudes, and slightly north of SP too but no better. I get a weird "level of detail" glitch when zoomed out too, but that's going to be dependent on the data layer as well as the graphics hardware in use.

Comment: As you can see from the image, the stations layer was imported as a CSV file containing latitude and longitude. I shall try to reproject these points into a new layer, if it functions then this is definitely a bug.

Answer (score 2):

As written in the comments, it is better to reproject your data into exotic target CRS and don't rely on the OTF reprojection of the software:

[image]

For raster data, you may append `-wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000` to the gdalwarp command line to avoid nasty artefacts along the 180° meridian.

Comment: Didn't know that gdalwarp trick.

Comment: See my answer on http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173766/convert-a-geotiff-web-mercator-into-an-azimuthal-equidistant-projection and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/126747/what-coordinate-system-is-this-netcdf-raster

Comment: Could you explain what is an "exotic target CRS"?

Comment: Because all meridians touch in one point. You would not see that in "normal" mercator or transverse mercator projections of populated parts of the world. There you only have more ore less bended lines. Mathematically, this is far more simple than mapping the poles correctly.