# Convert a geotiff web-mercator into an azimuthal equidistant projection

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, geotiff-tiff

I have a geo-referenced tiff file, in the web-mercator projection; and I need it converted to an azimuthal equidistant projection.
I'm new to GIS and can't figure out how to do this.

I'm open to using any program for any OS, as long as it gets the job done.

And as far as OS-specific is concerned, I have computers with : Linux-Debian, Mac OX 10.6.8, Windows 7, and Windows XP.

Comment: What, if anything, have you tried so far?  Do you have any GIS software already? If not, are you only looking for open source options?

Comment: I've tried 'GRASS GIS' and QGIS, but couldn't figure out how to use them.

Comment: I've also tried Gprojector from nasa, which I find very easy to use, but it only accepts 'plate carree' as the source

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your source tif is in Pseudo mercator, but the extent stored inside the file is in degrees. This can not be interpreted correctly by gdalwarp, and so it delivers the untouched source file. You can get the correct extent in pseudo mercator coordinates from https://github.com/mapnik/mapnik/wiki/XMLConfigReference : `-20037508.34, -20037508.34, 20037508.34, 20037508.34`. With that, you can set the extent with gdal_translate manually before reprojecting.

The target projection is not covered by EPSG, but ESRI has invented a code 102016, which is included in GDAL and QGIS as `EPSG:102016`:

```
+proj=aeqd +lat_0=90 +lon_0=0 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs
```

You will get nasty artefacts along the 180° meridian, so an extra option `SOURCE_EXTRA` is needed. A blind spot on the north pole will remain, because pseudo mercator does not cover it:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:3857 -of GTiff -a_ullr -20037508.34 20037508.34 20037508.34 -20037508.34 F:/Download/63575605298.3c.tif F:/Karten/merc_corrected.tif
gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:102016 -ts 8192 8192 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -of GTiff F:/Karten/merc_corrected.tif F:/Karten/world_aeqd.tif
```

[image]

Comment: great answer, very impressive, am removing the solution that I posted

Answer (score 1):

1. Load your raster layer into QGIS.
   Right click on the raster layer name in layer list and select *Save As...* from the popup menu. In the Save As dialog select a target format, name and an other CRS.
2. You can also use gdal_warp (GDAL Utilities) from the command line:

gdalwarp -s_srs +init=epsg:*yyyy* -t_srs +init=epsg:*xxxx* input_raster output_raster

s_srs is the source projection, t_srs is the target projection.

Comment: 1) With QGIS, from a source of 14mb, it takes a 100 minutes to save, to get an unreadable 4gb file.

Comment: 2) With gdalwarp, it does the conversion, but there's a distortion problem.
No matter what projection I convert it to, it looks way more distorted than it should be.
Is there a way to tell it the bounds of my map ? Would that solve the problem ?

Comment: Can you check the projection parameters on your machine? Are they correct? Do you know these values? 100 minutes on which operating system? Which QGIS version? Is the tiff compressed (`gdalinfo filename`)?

Comment: "Can you check the projection parameters on your machine?"
I'm not sure what you're asking, QGIS detects WGS 84.

"100 minutes on which operating system?"
Debian, Intel i3 4 core 3.07Ghz, 8Gb ram

gdalinfo returns that:

Comment: Driver: GTiff/GeoTIFF
Files: 3c.tif
Size is 8192, 8192
Coordinate System is:
PROJCS["WGS_84_Pseudo_Mercator",
    GEOGCS["GCS_Popular Visualisation CRS",
        DATUM["D_Popular_Visualisation_Datum",
            SPHEROID["Popular_Visualisation_Sphere",6378137,0]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
        UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],
    PROJECTION["Mercator"],
    PARAMETER["central_meridian",0],
    PARAMETER["false_easting",0],
    PARAMETER["false_northing",0],
    UNIT["Meter",1],
    PARAMETER["standard_parallel_1",0.0]]

Comment: Origin = (-180.000000000000000,85.051128778228602)
Pixel Size = (0.043945312500000,-0.020764435736872)
Metadata:
  AREA_OR_POINT=Area
Image Structure Metadata:
  COMPRESSION=LZW
  INTERLEAVE=PIXEL
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (-180.0000000,  85.0511288) 
Lower Left  (-180.0000000, -85.0511288) 
Upper Right ( 180.0000000,  85.0511288) 
Lower Right ( 180.0000000, -85.0511288) 
Center      (   0.0000000,   0.0000000) 
Band 1 Block=8192x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Red
Band 2 Block=8192x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Green
Band 3 Block=8192x1 Type=Byte, ColorInterp=Blue

Comment: I managed to make a quicker render in QGIS, by changing the number in "column", but I have the same problem than with gdal, the result is wildly distorted.

Comment: QGIS version 2.4

Comment: It looks like the program interprets it as a "plate carree" no matter what projection I choose.

Comment: The projection parameters are stored in a SQLite database in case of QGIS (see: /usr/share/qgis/resources/srs.db). If don't know the parameter Values of the used projection, you had better to try to transform a single point for which you know the coordinates in both projection. This way you can compare the transformed and the original coordinates after transforming.

Comment: When you say the result is 'way more distorted than it should be' what projection is your QGIS project in?  What your telling gdalwarp to do is distort the pixels, so trying opening a new project and bringing the warped raster in as the first dataset so that the project will take that output projection.

Comment: @Grant Humphries the source projection is a web-mercator (from google map), but whatever I do, both QGIS and gdalwarp act as if it were a 'plate carree'.

Comment: @sbom can you provide any more info about your target projection, such as its EPSG code or proj4 string?  From a quick Google search it looks like Plate Carre at least has a lot in common with azimuthal equistant projections, if it is not one

Comment: http://file.2sfa.com/upload/63575605298.3c.tif

Comment: @Grant Humphries Here's the file, that should make it easier.

Comment: for the target projection, it's "north pole azimuthal equidistant"