# Assigning known georeference to PNG using GDAL

Tags: gdal, geotiff-tiff

I have a little experience with GDAL using the command line. However I am not sure where to start with this issue as it deals with adding projection to an image and I have never done it from scratch.

I have a PNG image (radar/rain data) that I need to convert to geoTIF. I was told what the projection and bounding coordinates are, but I am not sure if I have **enough** information or even if I am doing it right.

Here is the information I was given :

```
Longitude: -102.328, -93.7296
Latitude: 26.0468, 33.3013
Projection: AzimuthalEquidistant.
```

For additional clues, I know the image was generated by in python with Py-Art (weather radar tools). I found information on projection output with this tool at  [this link](https://github.com/ARM-DOE/pyart/blob/master/pyart/io/output_to_geotiff.py), which states about image generation :

> The GeoTIFF can be the standard Azimuthal Equidistant projection used
>       in Py-ART, or a lat/lon projection on a WGS84 sphere.

So, I know the image was generated using the first option, but is this enough information to properly georeference my image? I see projection code in that link but it seems it is for their latter option (non standard Azimuthal Equidistant Projection). My end goal is to get the PNG projected to EPSG:3857 for Mapbox, but I am not sure how to get there. Here is what I have tried :

So, from what I read online, Azimuthal Equidistant Projection is also known as EPSG:4326. Perhaps what I am trying is too simple - but here was my command using what I believe are the coordinates and projection :

```
gdal_translate -of Gtiff -a_ullr -102.328 33.3013 -93.7296 26.0468 -a_srs EPSG:4326 image.png image2.tif
```

I then used this command to get to EPSG:3857 :

```
gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:3857 image2.tif image2-projected.tif
```

I verified that the final image was wrong (image2-projected.tif).

What am I doing wrong? I see from other examples online that there are "proj4" strings and SRS data, but I don't exactly understand what needs to be added and how to add it (if anything.)

Last, here is the image itself for completeness, and  [this is a public google drive link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AN07PnHFKwh2IwaWZZcQ_c0t1t0KwsP6/view?usp=sharing) to get the actual PNG :

[image]

Comment: Related https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/173766/convert-a-geotiff-web-mercator-into-an-azimuthal-equidistant-projection > -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000

Comment: Hi, I saw the link there. Are you saying that code "without" the SOURCE_EXTRA component would guide me? I am confused

Comment: Ah, I see their line of code.. "gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:3857 -t_srs EPSG:102016 -ts 8192 8192 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 -of GTiff F:/Karten/merc_corrected.tif F:/Karten/world_aeqd.tif
" but I am not sure what -ts means or how this could apply to my issue.

Comment: it's nowhere near enough info, need to know the parameters of aeqd - centre lon, centre lat, datum - those three at very least, and maybe the lonlat values are the corners? could guess but that's all you've got with this info, 4326 is longlat not aeqd

Comment: forget source_extra that has nothing to do with this, you just have missing metadata

Answer (score 1):

Commands:

```
$ gdal_translate -of VRT -a_srs EPSG:4326 -a_nodata 255 3lXUn.png 3lXUn.vrt -a_ullr -102.328 33.3013 -93.7296 26.0468
$ gdalwarp -overwrite -s_srs EPSG:4326 -t_srs EPSG:3857 -co COMPRESS=LZW 3lXUn.vrt 3lXUn.tif
```