# WKT for EPSG:4326 with LON 0 to +360 instead of -180 to +180

Tags: coordinate-system, geoserver, proj, well-known-text, grib

I have `GRIB2` files that seem to be in a projection similar to `EPSG: 4326`, except that instead of longitude between -180 and +180 it is between 0 and 360.

My intention is to get these files into `geoserver` and allow the data to be queried and reprojected at will through the `WMS`. I can get these files into `geoserver` with the GRIB extension, but I get a null pointer error when I attempt to reproject to mercator. I assume that this error occurs because data lies outside the -180 to +180 longitude bound.

I had attempted to just reproject the GRIB files with gdal_translate, using the `PROJ4` `+lon_wrap=180`option, but that operation takes forever and produces a far larger output file for some reason.

From what I understand, I can fix this situation by creating a custom projection in `user_projections/epsg.properties`that describes the CRS of these GRIB files. A custom projection for geoserver must be in the `WKT` format.

**TL;DR:** How do I write a `WKT` that describes a lat/lon coordinate system similar to `EPSG: 4326` but with longitude ranging from 0 to +360 instead of -180 to +180?

Here is the **gdalinfo** for one of these GRIB files. The file depicts the continental United States:

```
Size is 2847, 1517
Coordinate System is:
GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
Origin = (229.982699929725896,55.001944129287601)
Pixel Size = (0.024600140548138,-0.023088258575198)
Corner Coordinates:
Upper Left  (     229.983,      55.002) (229d58'57.72"E, 55d 0' 7.00"N)
Lower Left  (     229.983,      19.977) (229d58'57.72"E, 19d58'37.40"N)
Upper Right (     300.019,      55.002) (300d 1' 9.48"E, 55d 0' 7.00"N)
Lower Right (     300.019,      19.977) (300d 1' 9.48"E, 19d58'37.40"N)
Center      (     265.001,      37.490) (265d 0' 3.60"E, 37d29'22.20"N)
```

**gdalsrsinfo**:

```
PROJ.4 : '+proj=longlat +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +no_defs '

OGC WKT :
GEOGCS["Coordinate System imported from GRIB file",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
    PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

Screenshot from QGIS:
[image: QGIS screenshot]

Edit: This is not a duplicate. I have seen the answer from the referenced question, and it is not satisfactory. The operation takes too long to complete and produces a file that is entirely too large.

Edit #2: Added a link to the GRIB file:
 http://furlender.com/ECMWF_2017052412.grib2

Comment: There's no parameter that I know of in the WKT1 or 2 specifications. Could you re-georeference the file?

Comment: Really... thats too bad. You can define all these complex projections but you can't just offset the latitude by 180?

Comment: Can you share a download link for the file?

Comment: http://furlender.com/ECMWF_2017052412.grib2 @dbaston

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this that actually gets you a WKT file? I'm having the same problem trying to serve up NetCDFs of climate model output in Geoserver :/

Comment: @rensa Nope - I ended up just warping it with gdalwarp. From what I can tell, there's no way to produce a WKT that describes this.

Comment: No sweat—it turns out that Geoserver supports longitude > 180 for WMS as of 2.10, so I ended up switching from WCS to WMS. I lose some ability to query and style the data client-side, but that's okay in my use case. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply build a vrt file around your source grib with

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -a_ullr -130.0173001 55.0019441 -59.9870389 19.9746766 ECMWF_2017052412.grib2 ECMWF180.vrt
```

which is just 47kB large. The extent is calculated by hand. Similar to [How to reproject raster from 0 360 to -180 180 with cutting 180 meridian](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian) you might as well run

```
gdal_translate -of VRT -b 1 ECMWF_2017052412.grib2 temp.vrt
gdalwarp -overwrite -t_srs WGS84 temp.vrt ECMWF180.tif  --config CENTER_LONG 0
gdalinfo ECMWF180.tif
```

to extract it from the first band. The grib file has 41 bands with a fairly high compression; converting all to tif uses over 1GB and 2 min calculation.

You might add `-a_srs EPSG:4326` to the simple solution if you don't mind the difference between the source sphere and WGS84 ellipsoid. The simple solution will work unless you hit the 0 or 180° meridians, while the second will work always.

Comment: This seems like a workable solution. Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

I just ran into this with similar GRIB data... both MRMS radar data and AirNow air quality data are projected in 0-360° longitude, I'm assuming to save space by using unsigned integers.

Using the "+pm" parameter of PROJ fixed this:

```
+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +pm=-360 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
```

For a MapServer layer, this worked out to:

```
PROJECTION
###    "init=epsg:4326"
       "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +pm=-360 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs"
END
```

I've not used GeoServer, but this *might* work for the WKT description:

```
GEOGCS["4326 plus 360",
    DATUM["unknown",
        SPHEROID["Sphere",6371229,0]],
    PRIMEM["Custom",-360],
    UNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433]]
```

The reason for the **"-360"** is that the coordinates listed in the original question (as well as my own) have an Upper Left of ~230°, when that should actually be translated/rotated to -130°. i.e.: (230-360) = -130°.

Answer (score 3):

Although these solutions might have worked for some, in my case, I needed to do rendering transformations of .grib2 rasters on the fly. Geoserver WMS reprojection worked well for the raster itself but the created contours and wind arrows were created only for **0 - 360** longitude and not for -180,0.

Although I wanted to avoid using gdalwarp in my workflow, I had to change my mind and had to warp the grib2 to .tif, which finally works.

`gdalwarp -t_srs WGS84 input360.grib2 output180.tif --config CENTER_LONG
0 -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=100 -overwrite`

Answer (score 2):

You might want to give [wgrib2](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/) a try. From this file of [wgrib2 tips & tricks](http://www.ftp.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/wd51we/wgrib2/tricks.wgrib2) is the following:

> (42) I want to convert a grid to -180 to 180 grid.
>
> Assuming that you have IPOLATES installed and IPOLATES supports the grid, then you can do:
>
> ```
> wgrib2 In.grb -new_grid_winds earth -new_grid latlon 180:361:1 -90:181:1 out.grb
> ```
>
> If you don't want an 1x1 degree grid, you would have to change the grid definition.

In my experience, "assuming that you have IPOLATES installed" is equivalent to "assuming that you compiled wgrib2 yourself," but perhaps there are binaries with IPOLATES out there somewhere.

Comment: This looks like a potential solution to my problem, but when I use a 1x1 grid I get a tiny file with a very pixelated grid. How do I find out the dimensions of my original grid? I thought it might be "Size is 2847, 1517" from `gdalinfo`, but using 180:361:1517 -90:181:2847 out.grb gave me errors.

Comment: I think the example from the FAQ might have a typo. The syntax is `min:ncells:resolution`. Sounds like your inputs are global at 1/8-degree resolution, so you could do `-new_grid latlon -180:2880:0.125 -90:1440:0.125`.

Comment: That gets me closer, but when I do gdalinfo on the resulting file I get
Upper Left  (     179.938,      99.562) (179d56'15.00"E, 99d33'45.00"N)
Lower Left  ( 179.9375000, -90.0625000) (179d56'15.00"E, 90d 3'45.00"S)
Upper Right (     535.812,      99.562) (Invalid angle, 99d33'45.00"N)
Lower Right (     535.812,     -90.062) (Invalid angle, 90d 3'45.00"S)
Center      (     357.875,       4.750) (357d52'30.00"E,  4d45' 0.00"N)

Comment: [This page](http://www.cpc.ncep.noaa.gov/products/wesley/wgrib2/new_grid.html) has a better description of the latlon parameter. You need start point (which is not 180,-90), number of cells, cell size so it's basically regeoreferencing the data if you use the same cell size.

Comment: this was my latest attempt with wgrib2:
wgrib2 ECMWF_2017052412.grib2 -new_grid_winds earth -new_grid latlon -130.0173001:2847:0.0174532925199433 19.9770559:1517:0.125 out.grb

Comment: but for some reason it gives me a grid that starts at 279.663 longitude

Comment: ... which might proove that your wgrib2 build is without IPOLATES.

Comment: @MikeFurlender The `-new_grid` command isn't working for me either on this file. Glad you were able to find a solution with GDAL.

Answer (score 2):

`+pm=-360` aligned the data for me in mapserver but still wouldn't render properly. I had to replace it with `+lon_wrap=180` to get it to work