# Distortion in NetCDF served to Leaflet with Geoserver

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, netcdf

I'm attempting to serve netCDFs to a Leaflet map using Geoserver (2.12.1) and its NetCDF extension. I can set up the layers and get Leaflet to receive tiles over WCS 1.0.0 without a problem, but the tiles appear to distort as I scroll the map westward:

[image: Zoomed in view of Australia looks fine.]

[image: Zooming out also looks fine (although I note that tiles are not served in a 'wrapped' fashion).]

[image: But if I scroll westward, the WCS layer distorts.]

One possible reason is that, as in [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256215/wkt-for-epsg4326-with-lon-0-to-360-instead-of-180-to-180), these NetCDFs use longitude 0:+360, rather than -180:+180. (**EDIT:** I've confirmed that the distortion only occurs when tiles with X < 0 are requested.) I've tried a few solutions to preprocess the files to -180:+180, but they don't appear to change the output to Leaflet, even if I can verify the changed longitude in something like `ncview`.

Can anyone help me figure out what the problem is here (whether it's the longitude or something else)? Ideally, I'd like Geoserver to process the files as they are, as they're CF-compliant and I'd prefer to put less preprocessing on the folks who'll be giving me these files in the future if possible. Is there a version of EPSG:4326 that can handle this shifted longitude, or is there an option in Geoserver that can handle it? or is the problem something else entirely?

Comment: What's the CRS of the map tiles you're loading into Leaflet?

Comment: I've tried `EPSG:4326` for both native and declared, and also changing declared to `EPSG:3857` (with `Reproject native to declared` selected). Both seem to give the same result. It seems like the native CRS is read from the file, rather than being something I can configure?

Comment: I should also note that `EPSG:4326` are the only options for 'Request SRS' and 'Response SRS' under the layer's WCS settings. Is it possible to check on the Leaflet end what it's receiving?

Comment: Checking Geoserver's output, it's reporting that it's outputting EPSG:3857, and the envelope coordinates reported (in 3857) match the request URLs on the browser side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that Geoserver supports longitudes > 180, as well as continuous longitudinal wrapping, in WMS [as of Geoserver 2.10](http://blog.geoserver.org/2016/09/20/geoserver-2-10-beta-released/). Compare my WCS request, which gave the output above...

```
L.nonTiledLayer.wcs(
  geoserver_base + "/climdex-test/wcs?",
  {
    wcsOptions:
    {
      service: 'WCS',
      version: '1.0.0',
      request: 'GetCoverage',
      coverage: 'climdex-test:tasmax',
      crs: 'EPSG:3857',
      format: 'GeoTIFF'
    },
    displayMin: 220,
    displayMax: 320,
    // colorScale: 'rainbow',
    clampLow: false,
    clampHigh: false,
    uppercase: true,
    useCanvas: true,
    colorScale: 'magma'
  }).setOpacity(0.5).addTo(mymap);
```

... to a WMS request:

```
L.tileLayer.wms(
  geoserver_base + '/climdex-test/wms?',
  {
    service: 'WMS',
    version: '1.1.0',
    request: 'GetMap',
    layers: 'climdex-test:tasmax',
    format: 'image/png'
  }
).setOpacity(0.5).addTo(mymap);
```

[image: Proper scaling with WMS! Yay]

Can't find any explicit mention in recent changelogs of this feature being brought to WCS. It would certainly be nice, since I'd really like to be able to have more client-side control over the aesthetics of the layer, but it looks like this might be an acceptable compromise for now.

Comment: Any time you want a new feature/improvement brought to GeoServer this is your go-to guide: https://github.com/geoserver/geoserver/wiki/Successfully-requesting-and-integrating-new-features-and-improvements-in-GeoServer

Comment: Thanks, @AndreaAime! I'm not sure whether I have the bandwidth to work on it myself, so maybe a feature request isn't appropriate right now, going by that guide. I cross-postwd this question to geoserver-users, though, so maybe it'll generate some interest ☺️