# Changing projection from 0 360 to -180 180 for a simple raster

Tags: gdal, antimeridian

I'm trying to convert a raster with projections of (0, 360) to (-180, 180), and I've tried various SO solutions such as [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian), but it gave me a cropped output that doesn't have the western hemisphere.

The exact command that I've used is:

`gdalwarp -t_srs EPSG:4326 -te -180 -90 180 90 prec_high_res.tif rec_high_res2.tif`

Does anyone have any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: Looks like you are missing `--config CENTER_LONG 0`

Comment: Nope, gives the exact same thing

Comment: That's fine, thanks! (btw, do you know the answer to this question?)

Comment: you can have a look at [this solution?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256215/wkt-for-epsg4326-with-lon-0-to-360-instead-of-180-to-180)

Answer (score 2):

As you can see in following image, I have loaded in QGIS 3 a raster (world_0_360.tif) with longitudes from 0 360 and with latitudes from -90 90.

[image]

Afterward, I tried out an equivalent command used in accepted answer in [your link](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian):

```
gdalwarp -t_srs WGS84 world_0_360.tif world_180.tif  -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 0
```

and it ran without any error:

> Using band 4 of source image as alpha. Creating output file that is
>   2048P x 1024L. Processing world_0_360.tif [1/1] :
>   0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

After running above command, I also loaded resulting raster (world_180.tif) in QGIS. I assigned 50 % of transparency for both raster and it can be observed in following image that they match almost perfectly. So, @Frank Warmerdam procedure produces a good and reproducible result.

[image]