# Getting Canada shapefile to overlay model on QGIS?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geotiff-tiff, overlay, canada

How can I get Canada to overlap with the rest of my map?

I think this is a CRS problem but I really do not know how to solve it.

[image]

Comment: Maybe related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/how-to-reproject-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian

Answer (score 4):

Your raster layer is Pacific centered (0 ~ 360 degrees), while the bluish polygon is in -180 ~ +180 degrees space.

You will have to decide which x-range you will use. I think most people will choose to modify vector layer since Affine Transformation is available in many GIS software.

For instance, QGIS has **Translate** tool (Processing Toolbox > Vector geometry).

Below image shows an example to offset X by +180 degrees for GADM Canada coutry data.

[image]

Wait a while (it took me more than 10 minutes) then you will get;

[image]

<s>This pink Canada will fit with your raster layer.</s>

My bad, you will need **+360**; See below comment by [Vince](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/21577/vince).

---

If you want to edit your raster layer, I don't know any tool in QGIS (I will use SAGA).

Comment: Shouldn't the translation distance be +360, not +180? You'd want to move Canada north of the US, not onto Finland and Russia.