# Reprojecting of raster using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, precipitation

The raster I am trying to reproject is found here https://psl.noaa.gov/data/gridded/data.gpcp.html, and it's the first one "Monthly Mean" (so you might try to do it yourselves).

Problem is that when I load it into QGIS, the coordinate system it's not -180 180 but 0 360. I tried every possible solution I could fine, even the very popular on this post: [Reprojecting raster from 0 360 to -180 180 with cutting 180 meridian using gdalwarp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/reprojecting-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian-using-gdalw) but I can find no solution!

I tried to run the suggested command

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84" -t_srs WGS84 ~/0_360.tif 180.tif -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 --config CENTER_LONG 0
```

but the raster doesn't change at all; it stays 0 360

How do I do this?

---

Here is a picture of my problem.

[image]

Comment: The raster I downloaded it from the site does not have a (correct) CRS. THe raster shows up on Null island.

Comment: Actually I have no problem loading into QGIS, and I can extrapolate the data for the annual precipitation, but I cannot rotate my raster.

Comment: What CRS should the raster have (the original that can be downloaded)?