# Merging rasters in specified order using GDAL

Tags: python, gdal

Assume we have a raster file of the entire globe that has origin on Greenwich. What I'd like to achieve is to have a custom representations of map with different points being in the center. Something along the line - 'how weird the flat map would look like if [insert country here] was at the center'.

I can cut up raster file with `gdal_translate` at any longitude. The issue is putting it back together - when I create a virtual raster with providing cut up map segments on the input, it doesn't allow me to specify the order how these rasters will be glued together, always ending up with the exactly same looking map as I started to begin with.

My suspicion is - projection/metadata needs to be modified to reflect the proper origin point of the new map. But that's where I'm getting lost in the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually found my answer here:
[Reprojecting raster from 0 360 to -180 180 with cutting 180 meridian using gdalwarp](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/reprojecting-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian-using-gdalw)

```
gdalwarp -s_srs "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84" -t_srs WGS84 ~/0_360.tif 180.tif  -wo SOURCE_EXTRA=1000 \
           --config CENTER_LONG 0
```