Alignment issue
I'm having this issue with two different datasets from the IPCC on QGIS, while parts at the centre of the overlap, the edges are different, with the Americas being east and west on each map:

I have changed the CRS of both layers- as they initially had none- to be: OGC:CRS84 - WGS 84 (CRS84) - however they still show up like this.
The Affine Transformation does not let me select either of the layers.

Is there any way to make the edges overlap?


What do you mean by "I have changed the CRS layer"? What exact steps did you take?

Initially there was no recognized CRS- I changed both to be OGC:CRS84 - WGS 84 - but that did not help

I would suggest you try to find the correct CRS for each layer from the IPCC site.   If you cannot I would suggest in a new project you add a layer that has a known correct CRS.  Then add one of your layers.  Using Layer- Properties you can try different CRS definitions for that layer until it lines up with your known layer.  Repeat with the second layer.  Likely you will find they line up with different CRS definitions.  bugmenot123 was likely asking you for the precise steps (menu or tool settings) you used to assign a projection.  Defining a projection is different from reprojection.

The issue appears to be 0-360 versus -180 to +180 longitude ranges. Take a look at this Q & A: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/reprojecting-raster-from-0-360-to-180-180-with-cutting-180-meridian-using-gdalw

The issue appears to be 0-360 versus -180 to +180 longitude ranges. Take a look at this Q & A: gis.stackexchange.com/questions/37790/… –
Thanks- that solved the problem!
